# Como mostrar somente os dados preenchidos de uma consulta ao banco

Tags: php, mysql

No meu script, eu faço a consulta, porém tem alguns campos que estão vazios e no `foreach` ficam espaços vazios. Como faço para somente pegar os dados que tiverem preenchidos?

```
<?php

$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_so_wind WHERE ws_so_wind.id_soft = ws_soft_pos_contra.id_soft ");

foreach ($consulta as $pos) { ?>
  <li><?= $pos['pos']; ?></li> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta apenas verificar se o valor não é nulo com a função [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php).

```
foreach ($consulta as $pos) {
  echo !empty($pos['pos']) ? "<li>{$pos['pos']}</li>" : null;
}
```

Se o valor não for vazio, exibe o código HTML do elemento `li`, caso contrário, nada será exibido.

Comment: Gosto muito do operador condicional ternário !

Answer (score 1):

Introduzi uma condição no seu código.
Pode ser preciso acertar a condição de acordo com o conteúdo da tabela ou dos campos que você quer pular, mas este é o modelo:

```
<?php
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_so_wind WHERE ws_so_wind.id_soft = ws_soft_pos_contra.id_soft ");

foreach ($consulta as $pos) {
    if(!empty($pos['pos'])) {
        echo "<li>" . $pos['pos'] . "</li>";
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Só cuidado que o valor verificado pela função `empty` deve ser `$pos['pos']`, não apenas `$pos`.

Comment: corrigido, vlw!

Comment: brigado pela ajuda